# Assigning to an enum matrix c#

Tags: c#, matrix, reference, enums

So I have an enum called direction;

```
    enum direction 
    {
        right,
        down,
        cross,
        mmcross,
    };
```

and i have a 2 dimensional direction matrix called dir;

```
    direction[,] dir;
```

the problem is when i try to assign a direction to a member of direction matrix in a loop like

```
   dir[i, j] = direction.right;
```

or

```
   direction right = new direction();
   dir[i, j] = right;
```

the compiler returns "Object reference not set to an instance of object" exception. Btw i've opened up space for all members of the matrix with;

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++) 
                {
                    dir[i, j] = new direction();
                }
            }
```

So what am i missing, and/or misunderstanding, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Also, i forgot to mention, i did define array's bounds with;

```
           direction[,] dir = new direction[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
```

Comment: dir has not been initialized. The you haven't told the compiler how big the array is.

Comment: Please try to show your code as-is (how you wrote it), because it doesn't make sense at the moment...

Comment: Why are you instantiating an enum?

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating an instance of the 2 dimensional array; you only define it.
Use the `new` keyword to create the 2 dimensional array:

```
direction[,] dir = new direction[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, i did that too.